# Command set in /etc/rc.local on Ubuntu 13.04 is ignored

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I am trying to set my Ubuntu 13.04 machine in a way that, upon reboot, an instruction is executed and a program is launched with specific parameters, REGARDLESS of whether a user is logged on to the machine physically or by SSH.

This is the instruction that needs to be executed:

```
/root/ccminer/ccminer -a x11 -o stratum+tcp://drk.smartcoinpools.com:7903 -u XgZLPCQkGvvpK42jAAtgRHvs8J25xKn1XS -p picciolibeddi -q
```

I have modified, therefore, my /etc/rc.local as follows:

```
 #!/bin/sh -e
 #
 # rc.local
 #
 # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
 # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
 # value on error.
 #
 # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
 # bits.
 #
 # By default this script does nothing.


 /root/ccminer/ccminer -a x11 -o stratum+tcp://drk.smartcoinpools.com:7903 -u XgZLPCQkGvvpK42jAAtgRHvs8J25xKn1XS -p picciolibeddi -q

exit 0
```

I can't really understand why this instruction is totally ignored after rebooting, yet if I launch it manually from shell it works perfectly, so there are no errors of syntax in it.

I would appreciate it loads if you could please help me, bearing in mind that I need to run this command BEFORE any user is logged in.

Comment: Do you really have to start a miner with root privileges? Also, what's the problem with writing a simple upstart/systemd rule?

Comment: Try adding `>/root/c.log 2>&1` to the end of that command line and see if any error messages appear in the `c.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) Doesn't the `x11` option require that the program is launched while an xserver is running?

2) Apart from this you could try `cron`, using the `@reboot` directive.

3) You might also use the `screen` utility to daemonize your script.

4) Further you might use `sudo -u underprivileged-user ...` to prevent running the program as root.